# Release and autorelease

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, null

Suggest me the difference between the release , autorelease, drain , nil and null. 
When the dealloc method of the application is call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Release:** Decrease retain count by 1
>
> **Autorelease:** Deleayed release, will decrease retain count by 1 when the autoreleasepool is drained, which is most likely in the next run but not guaranteed.
>
> **Drain:** To drain the autorelease pool
>
> **Nil:** Null for objective C objects
>
> **Null:** Null for C pointers.

Just to put in the answer what @Kendall Helmstetter Gelner said, the dealloc method will get called when the retain count reaches 0.

Comment: Good response, but you forgot to add that dealloc is called when the retain count reaches 0.  It's a really simple system...

Comment: Can you give me the  brief explanation

Comment: @er - that is the brief explanation... you really should go and find a document somewhere on Objective-C memory management to understand better what is going on.  Basically retain counts up, release coutns down, and when the count is 0 dealloc is called.